# Is Unity still being worked on?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container

Just wondering if the P&P Unity is still being worked on, even if it's only by the community, or if P&P is still moving it forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so long till Unity 2.0 and Enterprise library 5.0 were released so yes P&P still works on Unity.

Comment: Excellent. It's odd that I see a lot of msdn docs saying "This is outdated, being kept for the individuals use". Whats the script?

Comment: That's because you are looking at documentation for old Unity's version.

Comment: Could be. It seemed to be standalone docs in p&P msdn, with no linkback to the source, so couldn't verify if it was old docs. Its looked like it was cast adrift, kinda pushing me towards windsor.

Comment: Least I know it's still being progressed.

Comment: Last checkin on codeplex source code for Unity was March 4, 2011. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Unity 1.1 has been retired and that's why the note about the outdated content was added. The landing page for Unity 1.1 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649080.aspx) has also another note with the link to the latest releases. It appears the child nodes don't have that link included. Of course, most people enter the docs not from the landing page but via search and end up somewhere in the middle of the doc set. Thanks, scope_creep, for pointing this out. I'll request these to be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

As a PM for Unity I can answer with a **most definitive 'yes'** to that question.

Here's what we've been working on recently:

- fixing interception bugs in Unity 2.0
- porting Unity Interception to Silverlight

As Chris pointed out in his comment, you can find code drops [here](http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). Expect a new one next week.

Also, if you have suggestions for improvements or feature requests, feel free to post them to our [uservoice forum](http://entlib.uservoice.com/forums/89245-general) or vote on the existing ones. My team and I will be reviewing them when planning future Unity releases.

On a separate note, Unity adoption is rising - both internally and externally. Several major Microsoft products are using Unity underneath, including Microsoft Exchange 2010, BizTalk 2009, Bing and Surface 2.0.

If I may, I'd like to invite members of the community to comment on my answer and post what projects/companies they are using Unity in and what their experiences are like.

Comment: Unity 2.1 release can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17866

Comment: ... and for Silverlight: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1623

Answer (score 0):

Unity 3.0 for .NET4.5 Preview has been [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2011/10/27/unity-3-0-preview-for-net-4-5.aspx). Check it out.

Can it get any more convincing than that? :)